# indexOf in Kotlin Arrays

Tags: arrays, kotlin

How do I get the index of a value from a Kotlin array?

My best solution right now is using:

```
val max = nums.max()
val maxIdx = nums.indices.find({ (i) -> nums[i] == max }) ?: -1
```

is there a better way?

Comment: `indexOf()` for arrays is not present in the standard library yet. I files this to our issue tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4347. Thanks for the report

Comment: `indexOf()` is now present in stdlib.  I have added an answer matching this.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to get the index of the maximum element you can use 'maxBy' function:

```
val maxIdx = nums.indices.maxBy { nums[it] } ?: -1
```

It is more efficient since it will traverse the array only once.

Comment: This is outdated, there is now stdlib functions available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518333/3679676

Comment: @Jayson, your answer with new `indexOf()` function doesn't outdate this answer in any way as it still excels with single traverse.

Comment: This answer works, but it doesn't make sense to do this considering standard lib functions `indexOf`, `indexOfFirst` and `indexOfLast`.  It is a work around for a missing thing that now isn't missing.  Therefore, outdated.

Comment: It's now replaced with `maxByOrNull`

Answer (score 14):

With current Kotlin (1.0) you can use [`indexOf()` extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-array/index-of.html) on arrays:

```
val x = arrayOf("happy","dancer","jumper").indexOf("dancer")
```

All [extension functions for arrays](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html#extension-functions) are found in the [api reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib).

In your example:

```
val maxIdx = nums.indexOf(nums.max())
```

Comment: Is there indexOfBy { it.name == "this" } ?

Comment: @danielgomezrico There isn't an `indexOfBy` but there is an [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) and an [`indexOfLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-last.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the item based on some predicate, then you can use [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) and [`indexOfLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-last.html) extension functions.

```
val strings = arrayOf("hello","world","hello")
val firstHelloIndex = strings.indexOfFirst { it == "hello" }
val lastHelloIndex  = strings.indexOfLast  { it == "hello" }
```