# Kotlin has array.indexOf but I cannot figure out how to do array.indexOfBy { lambda }

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has `array.indexOf(item)` but I cannot figure out how to do `array.indexOfBy { lambda }`.  Does it not exist?  I can `find` an item, but I cannot get its index at the same time.

Am I missing a function in the stdlib?

I can create a function with a loop that chekcs the items and returns when it finds the target.  Like this:

```
fun <T : Any> indexOfBy(items: Array<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Int {
    for (i in items.indices) { // or (i in 0..items.size-1)
        if (predicate(items[i])) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Then I tried to make it a little more functional using `forEach`:

```
fun <T : Any> indexOfBy(items: Array<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Int {
    (items.indices).forEach {
        if (predicate(items[it])) {
            return it
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Or I can do something silly like this which isn't very performant:

```
val slowAndSilly = people.indexOf(people.find { it.name == "David" })
```

And what looks best is maybe as extension functions:

```
fun <T: Any> Array<T>.indexOfBy(predicate: (T)->Boolean): Int =
        this.withIndex().find { predicate(it.value) }?.index ?: -1
fun <T: Any> Collection<T>.indexOfBy(predicate: (T)->Boolean): Int =
        this.withIndex().find { predicate(it.value) }?.index ?: -1
fun <T: Any> Sequence<T>.indexOfBy(predicate: (T)->Boolean): Int =
        this.withIndex().find { predicate(it.value) }?.index ?: -1
```

Is there a more elegant and idiomatic way to accomplish this?!?  I also don't see a function like this for lists, collections nor sequences.

*(this question is derived from the [comment on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762219/indexof-in-kotlin-arrays/34518333?noredirect=1#comment59191006_34518333))*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html)

```
arrayOf(1, 2, 3).indexOfFirst { it == 2 } // returns 1
arrayOf(4, 5, 6).indexOfFirst { it < 3 } // returns -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatives that are handy in some cases:

```
a.indices.first { a[it] == 2 } // throws NoSuchElementException if not found
a.indices.find { a[it] == 2 }  // null if not found
```